# j2ee - error regarding port numbers required by Tomcat Server at localhost

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Error:

> "Several ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

Answer (score 0):

You either need to shutdown whatever is listening on those ports or change the port number you want to run tomcat on.  I suspect tomcat is already running on your system.  You can check this on a *nix or Mac system on the command line with:

```
$ ps -efa | grep tomcat
```

To change the port number tomcat is running on modify the entry in the tomcat server.xml file (tomcat_installation_dir/conf/server.xml).  Full instructions can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/)